# Python Selenium - Any way to get send text within this textbox?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm tring to select a textbox to input some data into it, the problem is i don't know how to get it's element:

This is what i get whem i do inspect on it:

```
<input class=" input" maxlength="255" type="text" aria-describedby="" placeholder="" id="8624:0" data-aura-rendered-by="8628:0" data-interactive-lib-uid="28">
```

The thing is that this is basically to fill forms, and id, rendered by, and uid numbers change.
Is there anything i could try?

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the `<input>` element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input[type='text'][data-aura-rendered-by][aria-describedby]"))).send_keys("Smece")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class=' input' and @type='text'][@data-aura-rendered-by and @aria-describedby]"))).send_keys("Smece")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```